# 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сохранить картинку со штрихкодом:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

def show_barcode(message,tekUser):
    EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
    ean = EAN(tekUser.karta, writer=ImageWriter())
    fullname = ean.save('c:\\'+str(tekUser.chat_id))
```

Получаю ошибку `TypeError: **'NoneType' object is not callable**`

Определил что ошибка возникает при вызове ImageWriter()

Что я делаю не так и как правильно?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run   task(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:/SlawaBot/main.py", line 58, in inlin
    show_barcode(c.message,tekUser)

File "C:\SlawaBot\users.py", line 50, in show_barcode
    ean = EAN(tekUser.karta, writer=ImageWriter())

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
"Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/SlawaBot/main.py", line 126, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 415, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)

File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 439, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()

File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])

File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value

File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:/SlawaBot/main.py", line 58, in inlin
    show_barcode(c.message,tekUser)

File "C:\SlawaBot\users.py", line 50, in show_barcode
    ean = EAN(tekUser.karta, writer=ImageWriter())

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

tekUser.karta не NULL, проверял

Python 3.8, что и где править надо?

насчет pillow

Requirment alredy satisfied

Оба пакета в одной и той же папке

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: `tekUser` не None случайно?

Comment: Небось питон 3.8, а модуль под 3.8 еще не починили.

Comment: Думаю, `EAN` будет `None`. Кст, вам форматирование кода и трассы стека отформатировали, но вы в следующий раз сделайте это сами. Используйте форматирование кода. Выделите его и нажмите `{}` на панели инструментов, либо используйте символы ``` до и после кода

Comment: Вы забыли установить Pillow, поэтому ImageWriter стал None

Comment: @gil9red я почитал исходный код python-barcode, тут None может стать только ImageWriter

Comment: @andreymal, действительно: https://github.com/emfcamp/python-barcode/blob/2a99ee91d98519f8f296aa42cfea1fde37f80823/barcode/writer.py#L285 . Думаю, установка `pillow` поможет: `pip install pillow`

Comment: "насчет pillow Requirment alredy satisfied" - он точно установлен туда же, куда и barcode?

Comment: Вобщем сделал так:  ean= barcode.get('ean13', tekUser.karta, writer=ImageWriter()) fullname = ean.save('c:\\'+str(tekUser.chat_id))  и все заработало. Еще бы понять почему